# LWC [object Object] returns undefined when trying to access property values

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, javascript-debugging

I have data returned from apex as a string:

```
[{"Rank":1,"Points":61,"Name":"Susan Johanson","Id":"0038d00000ANPt7AAH"},{"Rank":2,"Points":23,"Name":"Barry Bronze","Id":"0038d00000ANPtcAAH"}]
```

I use the below to try and access the different values for each object to create my leaderboard...

```
export default class Tbg_leaderboard extends LightningElement {
    allTBGContacts;
    error;

    connectedCallback(){
        getRankedContacts()
        .then(result => {
            console.log('>>>>>>>>>>>>' + result);
            this.allTBGContacts = JSON.parse(result);
            console.log('>>>>>>>>>>>>' + this.allTBGContacts);
            console.log('>>>>>>>>>>>>' + this.allTBGContacts[0]);
            console.log('>>>>>>>>>>>>' + this.allTBGContacts[0].id);
           
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.error = error;
        });
    }
```

The console.logs seen in the .then() shows as follows:

```
[object Object],[object Object]
[object Object]
undefined
```

What do I need to do / change to be able to access these values?

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is case sensitive. In your JSON its mentioned as `Id` whereas you are printing `id`.

Change it to `Id` and it should work.

Comment: Wow... what a stupid mistake by me. It's one of 'those' days. Thank you for being a second set of eyes and helping. Appreciate it.